# Azure NSG(network security group) service tag "ApplicationInsightsAvailability" can not work with inbound ip range security rule

Tags: azure, kubernetes, networking, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

## Context

- AKS(Azure Kubernetes Service)
- [nginx-ingress](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/nginx/nginx-ingress) helm chart as ingress controller

## What am I trying to do?

- Whitelisting IP ranges that can access service from internet through ingress controller
- Whitelisting azure network service tag "ApplicationInsightsAvailability", so availability test does not get blocked

## The tests I have done

1. Test: When whitelisting service tag "ApplicationInsightsAvailability" only

```
controller:
  service:
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-allowed-service-tags: "ApplicationInsightsAvailability"
```

> This snippet is "nginx-ingress" ingress controller configuration information in yaml format

Result: The availability test traffic can reach the service

2. Test:

- Whitelisting service tag "ApplicationInsightsAvailability"
- whitelisting ip ranges

```
controller:
  service:
    loadBalancerSourceRanges:
    - 1.1.1.1/32 # this is a dummy ip range for demonstration
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-allowed-service-tags: "ApplicationInsightsAvailability"
```

Result:

- The availability test traffic can not reach the service
- IP range whitelisting works

3. Test

- Whitelisting service tag "ApplicationInsightsAvailability"
- Manually apply ip ranges inbound security rule on NSG(Network Security Group)

Result:

- The availability test traffic can reach the service
- IP range whitelisting works

## Question

What might be the cause of availability test not working?